# Button on jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

I am writing a script using jQueryUI's button http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form. 
The button is pretty fancy looking.

Now, when I tried to use jQuery to change the display name of the button:

```
$('#signin').text("new name");
```

The Button revert to the original style of the browser, with no padding and etc. I don't know why change of style happens when I just change the display name of the button. Please suggest me a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To change button text use this :

```
$('#btnId').val('new-text');
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how. I used a span tag around the display name and just change text of that span tag.